# flashing STM32F745 with QStlink2 fails but works with stlink-gui

Tags: flash, arm, stm32, stm32f7

The toolset I am using (linux,eclipse,arm,gcc-arm-none-eabi) is working well for stm32f4xx when flashing with QStlink2.

For a new project, which uses a stm32f745, I see this is somehow failing at the level of flashing the generated .bin file.
The .bin file itself is fine, because when I flash it using stlink-gui, all works fine. So the problem appears to be in QStlink2

I am not stuck at the moment, but wanted to post this here to see if anyone else has the same issue? I will also post to QStlink page.

When I run the tool, I get the following output (my apologies if this is too long)

```
    Verbose level: 5
    Version: 1.2.3
    69 - Debug: Loading device list.
    70 - Info: Devices list loaded.
    70 - Debug: "RDPTR_KEY" -> 165 
    70 - Debug: "KEY1" -> 1164378403 
    70 - Debug: "KEY2" -> 3455027627 
    70 - Debug: "OPTKEY1" -> 135866939 
    70 - Debug: "OPTKEY2" -> 1281191551 
    70 - Debug: "SR_BSY" -> 0 
    70 - Debug: "SR_PER" -> 2 
    70 - Debug: "SR_EOP" -> 5 
    70 - Debug: "CR_PG" -> 0 
    70 - Debug: "CR_PER" -> 1 
    70 - Debug: "CR_MER" -> 2 
    70 - Debug: "CR_STRT" -> 6 
    70 - Debug: "CR_LOCK" -> 7 
    70 - Debug: "CR_PGSIZE" -> 8 
    70 - Debug: "ACR_OFFSET" -> 0 
    70 - Debug: "KEYR_OFFSET" -> 4 
    70 - Debug: "OPT_KEYR_OFFSET" -> 8 
    70 - Debug: "SR_OFFSET" -> 12 
    70 - Debug: "CR_OFFSET" -> 16 
    70 - Debug: "AR_OFFSET" -> 20 
    70 - Debug: "OBR_OFFSET" -> 28 
    70 - Debug: "WRPR_OFFSET" -> 32 
    70 - Debug: "devices_default" -> "flash_base" 
    70 - Debug: "devices_default" -> "sram_base" 
    70 - Debug: "devices_default" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "devices_default" -> "flash_size" 
    70 - Debug: "devices_default" -> "flash_pgsize" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L03xx" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L03xx" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L03xx" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L03xx" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L03xx" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L03xx" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L05xx" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L05xx" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L05xx" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L05xx" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L05xx" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L05xx" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L07xx" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L07xx" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L07xx" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L07xx" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L07xx" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L07xx" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Low/Med Density)" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Low/Med Density)" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Low/Med Density)" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Low/Med Density)" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Low/Med Density)" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Low/Med Density)" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (High Density)" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (High Density)" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (High Density)" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (High Density)" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (High Density)" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (High Density)" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat2" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat2" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat2" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat2" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat2" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat2" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat5/6" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat5/6" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat5/6" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat5/6" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat5/6" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx cat5/6" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L1xx (Dual Flash Banks)" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "SR_BSY" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "CR_STRT" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "CR_LOCK" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "CR_SER" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "SR_PER" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "CR_PGSIZE" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32L4xx" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F05x" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F05x" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F05x" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F05x" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F05x" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F05x" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F03x" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F03x" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F03x" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F03x" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F03x" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F03x" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F04x" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F04x" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F04x" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F04x" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F04x" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F04x" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F07x" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F07x" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F07x" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F07x" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F07x" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F07x" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F100" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F100" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F100" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F100" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F100" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F100" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Low Density)" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Low Density)" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Low Density)" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Low Density)" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Low Density)" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Low Density)" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Medium Density)" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Medium Density)" -> "chip_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Medium Density)" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Medium Density)" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Medium Density)" -> "buffer_size" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Medium Density)" -> "loader" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (High Density)" -> "core_id" 
    70 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (High Density)" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (High Density)" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (High Density)" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (High Density)" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (High Density)" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (XL Density)" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (XL Density)" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (XL Density)" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (XL Density)" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (XL Density)" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (XL Density)" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Connectivity)" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Connectivity)" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Connectivity)" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Connectivity)" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Connectivity)" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F10x (Connectivity)" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F2xx" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F2xx" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F2xx" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F2xx" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F2xx" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F2xx" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F301" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F301" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F301" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F301" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F301" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F301" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xB/C" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xB/C" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xB/C" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xB/C" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xB/C" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xB/C" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303x6/8" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303x6/8" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303x6/8" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303x6/8" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303x6/8" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303x6/8" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xD/E" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xD/E" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xD/E" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xD/E" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xD/E" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F303xD/E" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F37x" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F37x" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F37x" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F37x" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F37x" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F37x" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "SR_BSY" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "CR_STRT" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "CR_LOCK" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "CR_SER" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "SR_PER" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "CR_PGSIZE" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xB/C" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "SR_BSY" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "CR_STRT" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "CR_LOCK" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "CR_SER" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "SR_PER" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "CR_PGSIZE" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F401xD/E" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "SR_BSY" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "CR_STRT" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "CR_LOCK" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "CR_SER" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "SR_PER" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "CR_PGSIZE" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F411xC/E" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "SR_BSY" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "CR_STRT" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "CR_LOCK" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "CR_SER" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "SR_PER" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "CR_PGSIZE" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F405/415/407/417x" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "SR_BSY" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "CR_STRT" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "CR_LOCK" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "CR_SER" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "CR_PGSIZE" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F42x/43x" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "core_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "chip_id" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "flash_size_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "flash_int_reg" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "loader" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "SR_BSY" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "CR_STRT" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "CR_LOCK" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "CR_SER" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "CR_PGSIZE" 
    71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "buffer_size" 
    71 - Debug: New Transfer Thread
    72 - Info: "32 Device descriptions loaded." 
    15421 - Debug: ***[ bool MainWindow::connect() ]*** 
    15422 - Info: "Searching Device..." 
    15422 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::flush() ]*** 
    15449 - Info: "ST Link V2 / Nucleo found!" 
    15449 - Info: "Fetching version..." 
    15449 - Debug: ***[ stlinkv2::STVersion stlinkv2::getVersion() ]*** 
    15449 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::setExitModeDFU() ]*** 
    15449 - Info: "Changing mode to SWD..." 
    15449 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::setModeSWD() ]*** 
    15449 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getMode() ]*** 
    15450 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::setExitModeDFU() ]*** 
    15550 - Info: "Fetching mode..." 
    15550 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getMode() ]*** 
    15550 - Info: "Mode: Debug" 
    15550 - Info: "Fetching status..." 
    15550 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    15551 - Info: "Status: Core Running" 
    15551 - Info: "Fetching MCU Info..." 
    15551 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getCoreID() ]*** 
    15551 - Info: CoreID: 5BA02477
    15551 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::resetMCU() ]*** 
    15552 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getChipID() ]*** 
    15552 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at E0042000" 
    15553 - Info: CM3/4 Searching at E0042000
    15553 - Info: ChipID: 0x449
    15553 - Debug: Looking for: 0x449
    15553 - Debug: Found chipID
    15553 - Info: Device type:  "STM32F7xx" 
    15553 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::readFlashSize() ]*** 
    15553 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 1FF0F442" 
    15553 - Info: Flash size: 49152 KB
    30225 - Info: "Size: 31KB" 
    31411 - Debug: Writing flash
    31412 - Info: "Sending /home/marleen/workspace/eclipse-kepler/argus_eclipse/Debug/argus_eclipse.bin" 
    31412 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::resetMCU() ]*** 
    31413 - Info: Using loader
    31413 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::hardResetMCU() ]*** 
    31423 - Info: Writing from 08000000 to 08007c6f
    31423 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::resetMCU() ]*** 
    31427 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::flush() ]*** 
    31454 - Info: Loader ":/bin/loader_f4.bin" 
    31454 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 128 bytes to 0x20000000" 
    31455 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 128 bytes to 0x20000080" 
    31456 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 128 bytes to 0x20000100" 
    31457 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 128 bytes to 0x20000180" 
    31459 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 128 bytes to 0x20000200" 
    31460 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 128 bytes to 0x20000280" 
    31461 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 92 bytes to 0x20000300" 
    31463 - Debug: ***[ bool stlinkv2::writeRegister(quint32, quint8) ]*** 
    31463 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::readRegister(quint8) ]*** 
    31464 - Debug: Set register 15 to 20000000
    31464 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::runMCU() ]*** 
    31464 - Info: "Loader uploaded" 
    31464 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    31464 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::readRegister(quint8) ]*** 
    31465 - Debug: Current PC reg at 200000b2
    31465 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::flush() ]*** 
    31492 - Debug: Read Bytes 30720 from disk
    31492 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 4 bytes to 0x200007D0" 
    31492 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 4 bytes to 0x200007D4" 
    31492 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007D0" 
    31492 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007D4" 
    31493 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20000800" 
    31512 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20001000" 
    31533 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20001800" 
    31553 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20002000" 
    31573 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20002800" 
    31593 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20003000" 
    31614 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20003800" 
    31634 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20004000" 
    31654 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20004800" 
    31674 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20005000" 
    31695 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20005800" 
    31715 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20006000" 
    31735 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20006800" 
    31756 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20007000" 
    31776 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::writeMem32(quint32, const QByteArray&) ]*** "Writing 2048 bytes to 0x20007800" 
    31796 - Debug: ***[ bool stlinkv2::writeRegister(quint32, quint8) ]*** 
    31797 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::readRegister(quint8) ]*** 
    31798 - Debug: Set register 15 to 200000B4
    31798 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::runMCU() ]*** 
    31798 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    31798 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderPos() ]*** 
    31798 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007DC" 
    31798 - Debug: Loader position: 0x8000000
    31829 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    31829 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderPos() ]*** 
    31829 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007DC" 
...
    31952 - Debug: Loader position: 0x8000000
    31982 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    31983 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderPos() ]*** 
    31983 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007DC" 
    31983 - Debug: Loader position: 0x8000000
    32012 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    32013 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderPos() ]*** 
    32013 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007DC" 
    32013 - Debug: Loader position: 0x8000000
    32043 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    32043 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderPos() ]*** 
    32044 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007DC" 
    32044 - Debug: Loader position: 0x8000000
    32074 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    32074 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderPos() ]*** 
    32074 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007DC" 
    32075 - Debug: Loader position: 0x8000000
    32105 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    32105 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderPos() ]*** 
    32105 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007DC" 
    32106 - Debug: Loader position: 0x8000000
    32136 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    32136 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderPos() ]*** 
    32136 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007DC" 
    32137 - Debug: Loader position: 0x8000000
    32167 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    32167 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderPos() ]*** 
    32167 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007DC" 
    32167 - Debug: Loader position: 0x8000000
    32198 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    32198 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderPos() ]*** 
    32198 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007DC" 
    32198 - Debug: Loader position: 0x8000000
    32229 - Debug: ***[ quint8 stlinkv2::getStatus() ]*** 
    32230 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::getLoaderStatus() ]*** 
    32230 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 200007D8" 
    32230 - Error: Loader reported an error!
    32230 - Debug: ***[ quint32 stlinkv2::readRegister(quint8) ]*** 
    32230 - Debug: Current PC reg 200000b2
    32230 - Info: Transfer done 
    32230 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::hardResetMCU() ]*** 
    32234 - Info: "Transfer done" 
    32241 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::resetMCU() ]*** 
    32244 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::runMCU() ]*** 
    35319 - Debug: Verify flash
    37182 - Info: "Verifying /home/marleen/workspace/eclipse-kepler/argus_eclipse/Debug/argus_eclipse.bin" 
    37182 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::hardResetMCU() ]*** 
    37193 - Info: Reading from 08000000 to 08007c70
    37193 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::flush() ]*** 
    37221 - Debug: ***[ qint32 stlinkv2::readMem32(QByteArray*, quint32, quint16) ]*** "Reading at 08000000" 
    37243 - Error: Verification failed at 08000000 
     Expecting: 00 00 05 20 DD 02 00 08 E1 4E 00 08 E5 4E 00 08 E9 4E 00 08 ED 4E 00 08 F1 4E 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 58 00 08 F5 4E 00 08 00 00 00 00 C1 58 00 08 F9 4E 00 08 29 42 00 08 29 42 ...
6D 5D 4B 
           Got:FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF ...
FF FF FF 
    37243 - Debug: ***[ void stlinkv2::runMCU() ]*** 


2689151 - Info: "Disconnecting..." 
2689152 - Debug: Closing USB connection...
2689152 - Info: "Disconnected." 
2690109 - Info: "Transfer Aborted"
```

Comment: Does QStlink2 actually support F7 devices? From the look of that log it would appear to be treating it as an F4; whether an F4 flash algorithm is supposed to work on an F7 I don't know, but this rather suggests it doesn't...

Comment: there is a part in the log which mentions STM32F7xx:
71 - Debug: "device" -> "STM32F7xx" -> "core_id" 
...

Answer (score 0):

QStlinkv2 don't work for me too. It put 0ko on memory flash size. So I use stlink by texane.